# Compiler crashes with const auto

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, auto

I am using `Visual Studio 2010` with SP1. The following code crashes the compiler:

```
template <typename T>
class MyClass
{
public:
  typedef int my_int;

  const my_int foo();

};

template <typename T>
const auto MyClass<T>::foo() -> my_int
// auto MyClass<T>::foo() -> const my_int // THIS WORKS!
{
  return my_int(1);
}

int main()
{
  MyClass<int> m;
  m.foo();
}
```

Note the commented line that fixes the issue. Am I using `auto` properly here (i.e. `const` qualifier on `auto`)? Is the workaround essentially the exact same thing (i.e. can I safely use it until the compiler's bug is fixed)? And lastly, am I the only one experiencing this issue, if not, I will file a bug report.

**NOTE:** I realize that const here makes little sense. I was trying to replicate the bug in a smaller project where in the actual project I am returning a `const` reference to an object.

Comment: Might be caused by an extension or add-in. Finishes compiling with a few errors with my install.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious: What errors does it show? As far as I can see, that code should compile.

Comment: It does indeed compile: http://ideone.com/iaFxeu

Comment: Actually it [compiled with warnings](http://pastebin.com/hsz5rjR0) (oops)

Comment: @CaptainObvlious: Ah. That warning seems like it is due to the return value being passed by value. Other than that, since it compiles, the problem obviously is with my install of VS. Do you have VS2008 installed as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code is ill-formed in C++11:  if there is a trailing return type, then the "normal" return type must be `auto` (the C++11 specification states at 8.3.5[dcl.fct]/2 that "T shall be the single *type-specifier* `auto`," where `T` is the "type" that appears before the name of the function).

All compiler crashes are compiler bugs, so it is a bug that the Visual C++ 2010 compiler crashes when compiling your program.  This bug has been fixed, though; Visual C++ 2013 rejects the program with a proper compilation error.

Comment: +1 I was literally just going to post this, oh well, should have typed faster. In `clang` this is an error and it complains `function with trailing return type must specify return type 'auto'` but `gcc` does not.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize how old this question was; I just saw it appeared on the front page and figured it was new.

Comment: I was going through old posts and was cleaning up the tags and after I posted the edit I realized it was actually an interesting question.

Comment: An implementation could just define compiler crash as a kind of diagnostic.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of those cases where trying out code in multiple compilers may have helped you realize that using `const auto` with a trailing return type is an error. There are several [online C++ compilers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916000/online-c-compiler-and-evaluator). If you had tried out this code in `clang` you would have received the following error(*[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a3447998409bd632)*):

> error: function with trailing return type must specify return type 'auto', not 'const auto'

The relevant section in the draft C++ standard is section `8.3.5` *Functions* paragraph *2* which says (*emphasis mine*):

> In a declaration T D where D has the form
>
> ```
> D1 ( parameter-declaration-clause ) cv-qualifier-seqopt
>   ref-qualifieropt exception-specificationopt attribute-specifier-seqopt
>     trailing-return-type
> ```
>
> [...]**T shall be the single type-specifier auto**.[...]

Comment: I actually did try it here: http://ideone.com/iaFxeu but you are right, I should have tried out a few more compilers. Thanks for the links (+1)